# Different ways to show an image according to its size and window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I want to do the same thing as you can see at [youassist.org](http://youassist.org/).

Look at the image in the slide show, and try to resize the browser window*. You can see two "behaviors" on the displaying of the image:

1. with larger window the image will gradually zoom in;
2. with smaller window** the image doesn't zoom out but it scroll horizontally.

I'm trying to do that. This is what I've got so far, but it only works if I resize from a big window to a smaller window, but not vice versa.

Here is a fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/z8RpZ/5/

HTML:

```
<div class="page-header-2">
    <img class="img-header" src="http://youassist.org/assets/home1.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.page-header-2{
    height:350px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    width:100%;
    background:red;
}
.img-big{
    width: 100%;
}
.img-small{
    height: 100%;
    max-width: none;
}
```

Script:

```
var imgH = $(".page-header-2 img").height();
var divH = $(".page-header-2").height();

if(imgH <= divH){   
    $(".page-header-2 img").addClass("img-small");
} else {
    $(".page-header-2 img").addClass("img-big");
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    var imgH = $(".page-header-2 img").height(); 
    var divH = $(".page-header-2").height(); 

    if(imgH <= divH){   
        $(".page-header-2 img").removeClass("img-big");
        $(".page-header-2 img").addClass("img-small");
    } else {
        $(".page-header-2 img").removeClass("img-small");
        $(".page-header-2 img").addClass("img-big");
    }
});
```

---

*: resize the window gradually and don't go beyond the point where the site reorganizes itself as responsive site for mobile. I'm not interesting in that!

**: "smaller window" isn't correct, I think this behaviour occurs when the image size is smaller than the window size

Comment: I haven't downvoted it, but I can tell that it's possibly because the question is redacted in a very confusing way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an application for the "new" [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/background-size) rule. What you do is instead of putting it in an image tag, you put the image in the background of the container and then use a dummy element to set the aspect ratio.

```
<div class="img-header">
    <div class="aspect"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.aspect {
    padding-top: 50%;
}
.img-header {
    background: url(url) center center / cover;
    min-height: 200px;
}
```

Since you probably want to put content inside too, you need absolute positioning , as otherwise the dummy element (`.aspect`) will break positioning. For this, the container (`img-header`) needs relative positioning and the content needs absolute with top/right/bottom/left of zero. I created a version of the fiddle for this too.

JSFiddles:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/dualed/gkBM5/ (basic)
2. http://jsfiddle.net/dualed/gkBM5/1/ (with content element)

Comment: Wow! It seems precisely what I need, and it's awesome how it works without js! But I don't get the usefulness of the `aspect` div. If I remove it, the code works in the same way. Could you explain?

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your question a bit; the aspect element is to increase the image size while you increase the browser windows size while keeping the aspect ratio of the image. If you don't want this and only want to scale the background you can simply remove it and put your content directly in `.img-header`. You *should not* do absolute positioning then either.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with simple CSS. Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/XBuGc/

I removed all your javascript and added some CSS

```
.img-header{
width:100%;
height:auto;
min-width:450px; /* adjust as necessary */
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi David, this doesn't work because the image is inside a div and have to have the same height of the div. Then I should specify the height in pixel and not with auto. But with a fixed height it obviusly doesn't work. I've updated my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z8RpZ/5/ and added to yours the above question: http://jsfiddle.net/XBuGc/5/

Comment: @FredK, I can't picture exactly what you are wanting to do, but maybe using background-cover on the div is an option on the for you?? http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/